# converting binary sequences from one form to another form

Tags: python, binary

I have a file containing a primary number sequence at the top. I also have some similar secondary sequences, each of which matches the primary sequence except in one position, located under the primary sequence.

input:

```
[0001][0010][0100][1000]
[0001][1000][0100][1000]
[0001][0010][0100][0010]
[0100][0010][0100][1000]
```

What I need to do is convert the secondary sequences so that the non-matching number remains untouched while converting every other number to [0000] within he sequence.

Desired Output:

```
[0001][0010][0100][1000]
[0000][1000][0000][0000]
[0000][0000][0000][0010]
[0100][0000][0000][0000]
```

Comment: Your title says "binary", but are the values in the sequences binary or not?  Are they always four digits (and four of them in the sequence)?  What is the purpose of this transformation? (If it is homework, you need to say so.)  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The following should provide the desired result:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    data = [[b  for b in x.strip()[1:-1].split('][')] for x in f.readlines()]

for col, val in enumerate(data[0]):
    for r in data[1:]:
        if r[col] == val:
            r[col] = '0000'

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(['[' + ']['.join(r) + ']\n' for r in data])
```

which gives us out.txt:

```
[0001][0010][0100][1000]
[0000][1000][0000][0000]
[0000][0000][0000][0010]
[0100][0000][0000][0000]
```